# window.Print(); ignoring Div Selector

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, pdf

I have code that reads from a SharePoint list, stores the data in an array, then posts it to an HTML list to be printed. For the most part, it works and prints the page.

I have excluded the Print button and Search bar from the div container I am choosing to print, and it is still appearing in the print preview? Can I remove these elements from the print view/also move the margin of the Weekly Report header and everything closer to the top of the page?

Here is my snippet where it works:

```js
var data = [{
    "Team": "Eagles",
    "WeekOf": "2021-01-31",
    "Tasks": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    "Deliverables": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "NonBillable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    "Training": null,
    "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
    "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
  },
  {
    "Team": "Raiders",
    "WeekOf": "2021-01-31",
    "Tasks": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    "Deliverables": null,
    "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "NonBillable": null,
    "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    "Training": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
    "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
  },
  {
    "Team": "Vikings",
    "WeekOf": "2021-03-30",
    "Tasks": null,
    "Deliverables": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "Actions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    "Billable": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "NonBillable": null,
    "UpcomingEvents": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    "Training": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "Resource": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
    "Support": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."
  }
];

function onSuccess(data) {
  var listContent = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    listContent += '<li data-weekOf="' + data[i].WeekOf + '">';
    listContent += '<h2>' + data[i].Team + '</h2>';
    listContent += '<h4> Tasks </h4>';
    if (data[i].Tasks !== null) {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Tasks + '</ul>';
    } else {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
    }
    listContent += '<h4> Deliverables </h4>';
    if (data[i].Deliverables !== null) {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Deliverables + '</ul>';
    } else {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
    }
    listContent += '<h4> Personnel Actions </h4>';
    if (data[i].Actions !== null) {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Actions + '</ul>';
    } else {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
    }
    listContent += '<h4> Finance (Billable) </h4>';
    if (data[i].Billable !== null) {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Billable + '</ul>';
    } else {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
    }
    listContent += '<h4> Finance (Non-Billable) </h4>';
    if (data[i].NonBillable !== null) {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].NonBillable + '</ul>';
    } else {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
    }
    listContent += '<h4> Upcoming Events </h4>';
    if (data[i].UpcomingEvents !== null) {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].UpcomingEvents + '</ul>';
    } else {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
    }
    listContent += '<h4> Training </h4>';
    if (data[i].Training !== null) {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Training + '</ul>';
    } else {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
    }
    listContent += '<h4> Resource Request </h4>';
    if (data[i].Resource !== null) {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Resource + '</ul>';
    } else {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
    }
    listContent += '<h4> Support Request </h4>';
    if (data[i].Support !== null) {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Support + '</ul>';
    } else {
      listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
    }
    listContent += '</li>';
  }
  $('#report-summary').html(listContent);
  $('#under_txt').text(' ');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  onSuccess(data);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if ($.trim(value) == '') {
      onSuccess(data);
      return;
    }
    $('#under_txt').text(value);
    $('li').fadeOut(10);
    $('[data-weekOf=' + value + ']').fadeIn();
  });

});

function sortNewestFirst() {
  var elements = $('[data-weekOf]');
  elements.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date($(b).attr('data-weekOf')) - new Date($(a).attr('data-weekOf'));
  });
  $('#report-summary').html(elements);
}

function sortOldestFirst() {
  var elements = $('[data-weekOf]');
  elements.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date($(a).attr('data-weekOf')) - new Date($(b).attr('data-weekOf'));
  });
  $('#report-summary').html(elements);

}
$('a.printPage').click(function() {
  $('#report-summary').show();
  window.print();
  return false;
});
```

```css
h2 {
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

span {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#report-summary {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

#search {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

#myInput {
  text-align: center;
}

#under_txt {
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
@page { size:  auto; margin: 50px; }

@media print {
  #search,
  .printPage {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div id="search">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search for Week Of">
  </div>
  <a class="printPage" href="#">Print Page</a>
  <h1>Weekly Manager Report</h1>
  <p>Week Of<span id="under_txt"></span></p>
  <div id="report-summary"></div>
</div>
```

On this example, it does not work and still posts the search bar and print button:

```
.container h2{
 text-align: left;
 text-decoration: underline;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.container h1{
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.container ul {
  list-style-type: none !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin-left: 0px !important;'
  color: black;
}
ul.black{
 color: black;
}
p.black{
  color: black;
}
.container li{
    list-style-type: none !important;
}
.container#report-summary{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
span{
  font-size: 15px !important;
}
#report-summary{
  margin-left: 15px !important;
  margin-right: 15px !important;
}
#search{
  text-align: center !important;
}
p {
  text-align: center !important;
}
.container h4{
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: black;
}
#myInput{
  text-align: center !important;
}
#under_txt{
margin-left: 5px !important;
padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px !important;
color: black;
}
.ms-core-pageTitle {
display: none;

@page { size:  auto; margin: 50px; }
@media print {
  #search,
  .printPage {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div id="search">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search for Week Of">
  </div>
  <a class="printPage" href="#">Print Page</a>
  <h1>Weekly Manager Report</h1>
  <p>Week Of:<span id="under_txt"></span></p>
  <div id="report-summary"></div>
</div>
```

```
function loadData(url) {
  url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('WeeklyReport')/items?$select=DeliverablesSubmitted,MajorTasks,UpcomingTasks,UpcomingDeliverables,PersonnelActions,SupportRequest,ResourceRequest,Team/Value,Training,Upcoming,WeekOf,TravelODC";
  return fetch(url, { headers: { accept: "application/json; odata=verbose" } }) // make request
    .then((r) => {
      if (!r.ok) throw new Error("Failed: " + url);  // Check for errors
      return r.json();  // parse JSON
    })
    .then((data) => data.d.results);
}
loadData()
  .then((results) => {
      let data = results;
      var listContent = '';
      console.log(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var currData = data[i];
        listContent += '<li class="test" data-weekOf="'+currData.WeekOf.split("T")[0]+'">';
        console.log(currData.WeekOf.split("T")[0]);
       if(currData.Team !== null){
        listContent += '<h2>' + currData.Team.results.join(', ') +'</h2>';
        }else{
        listContent += '<h2>' + "Null" +'</h2>';
        }
       if(currData.MajorTasks !== null){
        listContent += '<h4> Major Tasks Completed </h4>';
        listContent += '<ul class="black">' + "- " + currData.MajorTasks.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "") + '</ul>';
       }else{
       }
       if(currData.DeliverablesSubmitted !== null){
        listContent += '<h4> Deliverables Submitted</h4>';
        listContent += '<ul class="black">' + "- " + currData.DeliverablesSubmitted.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "") + '</ul>';
       }else{
       }
       if(currData.UpcomingTasks !== null){
        listContent += '<h4> Upcoming Tasks</h4>';
        listContent += '<ul class="black">' + "- " + currData.UpcomingTasks.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "") + '</ul>';
       }else{
       }
       if(currData.UpcomingDeliverables !== null){
        listContent += '<h4> Upcoming Deliverables</h4>';
        listContent += '<ul class="black">' + "- " + currData.UpcomingDeliverables.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "") + '</ul>';
       }else{
       }
       if(currData.PersonnelActions !== null){
        listContent += '<h4> Personnel Actions </h4>';
        listContent += '<ul class="black">' + "- " + currData.PersonnelActions.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "") + '</ul>';
       }else{
       }
       if(currData.Upcoming !== null){
        listContent += '<h4> Upcoming G3G Events </h4>';
        listContent += '<ul class="black">' + "- " + currData.Upcoming.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "") + '</ul>';
       }else{
       }
       listContent += '</li>';
    }
 $('#report-summary').html(listContent);
 $('#under_txt').text(' ');
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#under_txt').text(value);
    if (value == "") {
      $("li.test").fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('li.test').fadeOut(10);
      $('[data-weekof=' + value + ']').fadeIn();
    }
  });
});
function sortNewestFirst(){
  var elements = $('[data-weekOf]');
  elements.sort(function (a, b) {
      return new Date($(b).attr('data-weekOf')) - new Date($(a).attr('data-weekOf'));
  });
  $('#report-summary').html(elements);
 }
function sortOldestFirst(){
  var elements = $('[data-weekOf]');
  elements.sort(function (a, b) {
      return new Date($(a).attr('data-weekOf')) - new Date($(b).attr('data-weekOf'));
  });
  $('#report-summary').html(elements);
 }
$('a.printPage').click(function(){
        $('#report-summary').show();
           window.print();
           return false;
});
```

This is how it posts: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no JS necessary to prevent items in the DOM from being printed. You can achieve it by using CSS, specifically a `@media` rule which, in this case, will hide the relevant content. Try this:

```css
@media print {
  #search,
  .printPage {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I implemented that, and it hides my print button. I need the button to be visible and after it is clicked, it should not appear in the print preview, same for the search bar.

Comment: My bad, I targeted the wrong media type. I've updated the answer, it should work correctly now

Comment: This works perfectly on the snippet provided in the question which has an array of data, when I implement it into my code that gets data through a fetch, it still posts the search bar and print button in the print preview? Why is this? I will add my snippet of CSS/HTML to OP

Comment: I even tried adding the !important tag to the ```@media print{}``` and it still doesn't do what it is supposed to.

Comment: The HTML & CSS is literally the same so I am unsure as to why it is not working in my crucial example. I can't view console or anything as well because when it opens the print preview it covers that part of the screen